# Prevent nonbreaking spaces from making an election completely non-responsive

Tags: bug, status-review, election, responsive-design

In any narrow enough window, entire paragraphs are on the same line when [voting for this election](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election):

[image]

(On phone, this is the only view. On desktop, you can make this happen with a narrow window.)

Anything on the grey is offscreen and needs to be scrolled to.

First line of answer #5:

> If a policy or company directive seemed to conflict with my beliefs and ideals, I'd first look at why there is a conflict - is it because it goes against my personal ideologies, I'll see if there's a way I can resolve that conflict within myself. If not, I'd hand in the diamond and go back to being a regular Code Golfer - it's important to make sure that you're able to moderate a community in good conscience. If the conflict went against my beliefs about how the community should be run, or how users should be treated, I'd raise an issue in the appropriate channels (whether that be on meta or some form of mod to SE communication line). If the conflict isn't resolved after that, and I felt it was serious enough that I couldn't continue as moderator in good conscience, I'd hand in the diamon

Second line:

> d.

On closer inspection this was due to someone using nonbreaking spaces in their nomination. It only broke the "Election" view, and only when the window was narrow (other views only had awkward word wrapping and didn't overflow). Can this be prevented from happening?

Comment: Yeah.... so, if you look at the comments on the nomination (on the nominations tab), you'll see there's something wrong with the formatting of this answer... it does really odd things and that seems to maybe be related to the editor interpreting the GH MD in a strange way... so I don't think this is a *general* issue, unless you've also seen it on non-Code Golf election pages?

Comment: It's working as expected on the MO election, so I think there's just something broken about that one nomination on CG and I'm not sure how to fix it. I... will see if I can find a way to poke at the MD and make it better.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen this and I definitely looked at the ELL election on my phone. When I looked at the CG submissions in a Unicode viewer, I didn't see anything unusual either.

Comment: I've made a couple of edits without improvement. I'll try to do an overhaul later today when I have more time. That said, no guarantee it'll be fixed, unfortunately.

Comment: Fixed it. :D Still not sure what broke the formatting entirely but repasting all of the answers from the preview text fixed the problem.

Comment: @Catija It looks like instead of spaces there were nonbreaking spaces (but I can only see that when I look very carefully at the revision history).  By the way I think some minor emphasis was removed in revision 9.

Comment: Ok. I'll see if I can fix it later.